# Visual Studio 2012 Run as Admin on Win 8 issues

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, runas

Whenever I try running VS2012 as Admin, whether through Right Click or Troubleshooter Assisstant, it just hangs.  It has a dialog saying opening file and it sits there forever.

Anyone else able to run VS2012 on Win 8 as Admin?

Comment: Do you have original version of VS2012?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by original.  I am using Premium Edition gotten through my MSDN Subscription.

Comment: I mean did you pay for it? We have original in our company and it work on `Run as administrator` properly!

Comment: yup, MSDN Subscriptions cost quite a bit of money.

Comment: If you pay for original version, It's simple, call Microsoft!

Comment: for me it works fine: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/superuser/VS2012_Win8_RunAsAdmin.PNG Make sure you install the VS2012 Update 2.